# How to prove this inequality for $a_{n}<5$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Let $a_{1}=1,a_{2}=2$ and be related by the recurrence
$$a_{n+2}=\dfrac{a^2_{n+1}(1+a_{n})+(1+2a_{n})a_{n+1}-a^2_{n}}{a_{n+1}+a^2_{n}+a_{n}+1}$$

for $n\in N.$

How can I show that
$a_{n}<5,n\in N$?

my idea: I think we have 
$$a_{n+2}=pa_{n+1}+qa_{n}$$

because we have
$$a_{n+2}a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}a^2_{n}+a_{n+2}a_{n}+a_{n+2}=a^2_{n+1}+a^2_{n+1}a_{n}+a_{n+1}+2a_{n}a_{n+1}-a^2_{n}\cdots (1)$$
then 
$$a_{n+1}a_{n}+a_{n+1}a^2_{n-1}+a_{n+1}a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}=a^2_{n}+a^2_{n}a_{n-1}+a_{n}+2a_{n-1}a_{n}-a^2_{n-1}\cdots (2)$$
(1)+(2)

Comment: I guess, there is no **simple** inductive proof, because the problem strongly depends on the starting values, even for the very small change $a_2=2.001$ we have $a_{34} = 5.0003454098 > 5$.

Comment: Experimentally (!) it seems that $5-a_{n+1}=\frac56(5-a_n)-\epsilon_n$ where $\epsilon_n$ is small and decreasing. This is equivalent to $6a_{n+1}-5a_n=5-[small expression]$

Comment: @gammatester It makes sense that the bound is dependent on the initial values. If we write the recurrence as $a_{n+2} =f(a_{n+1}, a_n)$, observe that $x = f(x,x) $. So a more general question could be to ask about the convergence for pairs of initial values. We know it converges on lines $y=x, y=0, x=0$. But there are places where the values alternate like $(x,y) = (-0.4, -0.6)$.

Comment: Considering $b_n=1+a_n$ yields $b_0=2$, $b_1=3$, $b_{n+1}=b_nb_{n+1}^2/(b_{n+1}+b_n(b_n-1))$. From which one can deduce that $(b_n)$ is increasing, that $(b_{n+1}/b_n)$ is decreasing and that $b_{n+1}/b_n\to1$. But to deduce that $b_n\lt6$ for every $n$ is another story...

Answer (score 1):

Let us start with @Did's simplified form of the recurrence relation (with typos corrected): $$b_{n+2}=\dfrac{b_nb_{n+1}^2}{b_n^2-b_n+b_{n+1}}\quad (n=1,2,...)\quad\text{with}\quad b_1=2\text{ and }b_2=3.$$Write $c_n:=\dfrac {b_{n+1}+b_n^2}{b_nb_{n+1}}\;(n=1,2,...).$ Then substituting for $b_{n+2}$ in the corresponding expression for $c_{n+1}$ and simplifying gives$$c_{n+1}=c_n\quad (n=1,2,...).$$Therefore $c_n=c_1=\frac76$ forall $n$; that is $(b_{n+1}+b_n^2)/b_nb_{n+1}=\frac76,$ or$$b_{n+1}=\dfrac{6b_n^2}{7b_n-6}.$$Now the map$f:x\mapsto 6x^2/(7x-6)$ satisfies $f(1)=f(6)=6$ and $1<f(x)<6$ for $1<x<6$ (the minimum is $\frac{144}{49}$ at $x=\frac{12}{7}$). Since $b_1\;(=2)$ is in this range, so are all $b_n$. Thus $b_n<6$ for all $n.$